# Unity Tile pallete isn't appearing in window tab

Tags: unity

I'm trying to add a **tile pallette** to my scene in Unity. But when I go to

Window - 2D there is no tile pallette option

[image: No **tile palette** option]

I'm using

v2019.2.11f1 (Personal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Unity version 2019 and up

1. Go to Window
2. Find package manager.
3. Look for 2D Tilemap Editor. (Wait for a few seconds to load all the packages)

Install it and you're good to go.